# How to control the unit of timestamp step in taosBenchmark of TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I try to use taosBenchmark to test the performance of TDengine, but I don't know how to set the time precision of timestamp step, is there any way to do it or I can only use the default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you use command-line, you can only use default time precision which is "ms", If you use json file configuration, you can set "precision" option under "dbinfo" to "ns"/"us" or "ms" to control the unit of timestamp step.